# What is the easiest way to create a generic template iterator that can iterate through std::map values, in particular?

Tags: c++

I'd like to have a generic template iterator that iterates through a container of elements and accesses a specific member of the element. For example, if I have a `map<string, int>`, I iterate on the map values in a way like this:

```
for (TheCoolIter i = TheCoolIter(my_map.begin()); i != TheCoolIter(my_map.end()); ++i)
    int val = *i;
```

and `*i` return `p.second`.

But if I iterate through a vector of struct-s `*i` returns `MyStruct::a_member`;

This iterator can used if a class has `std::map` internally but exposes an interface for enumerating the map values without knowing the map type and key type, for example.

EDIT1:

The same code should iterate on `std::vector<int>` and on the values of `std::map<string, int>`

EDIT2:

A [good example](https://gist.github.com/eruffaldi/93d09ed6644ae3fa279f).

Comment: How do you specify `a_member` to the iterator? Please provide more examples and the things you have tried on your own.

Comment: @ Vittorio Romeo, there can be some kind of a getter class that returns the reference to a member, or probably a pointer to a member.

Comment: Have you thought about using [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, something like this, or probably TheCoolIter<&type::member>(my_map.begin()) or TheCoolIter<MemberAccessor>(my_map.begin()), but with the map it should be SecondAccessor.

Comment: Alright, then next question: Do you want the same instantination to work with different containers? Or you're willing to add a container-specific iterator as an another template parameter? The first one would require more work, and would add some overhead.

Comment: Have you tried boost::tranform_iterator yet?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, no, there should a specific template instantiation for each container/iterator type.

Comment: @paler123 I took a look, at least it is a good example

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Then it seems somewhat trivial. Have you tried writing it yet?

Comment: Do you need the iterator, or is a ranged-for acceptable? `for (auto & val : myMap | boost::adaptors::map_values)` [works well](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html) for me

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, probably yes, it is really trivial. It should be something like this https://gist.github.com/eruffaldi/93d09ed6644ae3fa279f. But there is a lot of typing... for const and non-const, etc...

Comment: @Caleth boost::adaptors::map_values is a good example and something close to what I need.

Comment: @NathanOliver how can they help?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky So you know how to do it in general, but not sure if you're able to get all details right? Then why not actually start writing the thing, and ask here if you face any problems?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes probably my question is too broad, but at least I found a good example boost::transform_iterator<xfunc,map::iterator>, now I am starting to use my keyboard and type the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) has `transform` views:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> v /* = ..*/;

for (int e : v | ranges::view::transform(&MyStruct::a_member)) { /*..*/}
for (int e : v | ranges::view::transform([](const MyStruct& s){ return -s.a_number; })) { /*..*/}
```

and with "`pair`", there are already some helpers

```
std::map<string, int> m /* = ..*/; // or std::vector<std::pair</*const*/std::string, int>>

for (int e : m | ranges::view::values) { /*..*/ }
for (const std::string& keys : m | ranges::view::keys) { /*..*/ }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just have function overloads:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
auto coolValue( const std::pair<Key,Value> &p ) { return p.second; }

auto coolValue( const MyStruct &st ) { return st.a_member; }
```

then use it in a loop:

```
for( auto i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i ) {
   auto val = coolValue( *i );
   ...
}
```

if you need more generic solution you should look into [Boost.Iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library, and into [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) in particular

Comment: I need to iterate without knowing that I need 'coolValue'. The same code should iterator on std::vector<int> and on the values of std::map<string, int>

Comment: Yes, probably I need something like boost::transform_iterator

Comment: I'll mark this as answer if you remove 'CoolValue'. The answer is boost::transform_iterator.